# "If exists" in databricks

Tags: t-sql, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have statement in t-sql. which checks the date and if its true then it will continue execution (insert into).

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT dateadd(day,+1,CAST(SnapshotDate as date))  FROM CONFIG.[SnapshotDateTables] WHERE dateadd(day,+1,CAST(SnapshotDate as date))  = CAST(GETDATE() as date))


INSERT INTO [DWH].[F_TIMESHEET_FREEZE]
```

How can I achiave similar thing in databricks using sql or pyspark, no preference.

Comment: That's an odd way of working, Simply do the insert and use a `where` as a filter. Also the expression in the `select` is redundant it's ignored, and integers are positive by default ;)

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below in databricks SQL using `where` clause as suggested in comments.

```
%sql

insert  into <table_name1> select  [column1],[column2]..  from <table_name2> where [column] =  <Value>;
```

Go through the below demonstration:

Here I have 2 rows in sample2 table.

[image]

I have created the required where we need to insert values and I am inserting the table on condition like below.

```
%sql

insert  into sample1 select  *  from sample2 where name =  'Laddu';
```

**when condition is true:**

[image]

**when condition is false:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL in Databricks:

```py
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT DATE_ADD(SnapshotDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  FROM CONFIG.SnapshotDateTables
  WHERE DATE_ADD(SnapshotDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = CURRENT_DATE()
)
INSERT INTO DWH.F_TIMESHEET_FREEZE
SELECT ...
```

Then replace `SELECT ...` with your query  for inserting into the `DWH.F_TIMESHEET_FREEZE` table.

If you are using PySpark in Databricks:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

snapshot_exists = spark.sql("""
  SELECT DATE_ADD(SnapshotDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS NextSnapshotDate
  FROM CONFIG.SnapshotDateTables
  WHERE DATE_ADD(SnapshotDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = CURRENT_DATE()
""").count() > 0

if snapshot_exists:
    df_insert = ...
    df_insert.write.insertInto("DWH.F_TIMESHEET_FREEZE")
```

Replace `df_insert = ...` with your DataFrame creation logic for inserting into the `DWH.F_TIMESHEET_FREEZE` table.